# Why cannot Reducer.class used as a real reducer in Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I noticed that Mapper.class can be used as a real mapper in a phase, together with a user-defined reducer. For example,

```
Phase 1:
Mapper.class ->  WordCountReduce.class
```

This will work.
However, Reducer.class cannot be used the same way. Namely something like

```
Phase 2:
WordReadMap.class ->  Reducer.class
```

will not work.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't as long as the outputs are of the same class as the inputs. The [default in the new API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.4/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html) just writes out whatever you pass into it, it's implemented as

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for(VALUEIN value: values) {
      context.write((KEYOUT) key, (VALUEOUT) value);
    }
}
```

For the old API, it's an `interface`, and you can't directly instantiate an interface. If you're using that, then that's the reason it fails. Then again, the `Mapper` is an interface as well, and you shouldn't be able to instantiate it...

Comment: yeah... I just made some mistakes on this... you are absolutely right.